Any suggestion on python libs, could search a given subtree(by sequence of nodes and node data field) from another tree?
I am now looking for a python library, which has capability to search a subtree by given the sequence of nodes, from another(much deeper and bigger) tree. For example if I have a tree structure(in this example it's filesystem, but I would like to be more general so think about different kind of IoT devices connected into a tree structure, with different names and status like "Occupied" / "Free".) like this:
├─ node_modules/
│  ├─ new_folder/
│  │  ├─ new_file
│  ├─ new_file
├─ public/
│  ├─ favicon.ico
│  ├─ index.html
│  ├─ robots.txt
├─ src/
│  ├─ index.css
│  ├─ index.js
├─ .gitignore
├─ package.json
├─ README.md

Now I would like to search if sequence "src/index.css" exists, as well as both "src" and "index.css" has creator named "John Doe".
Thanks!
A python library which could:

Build a tree by given nodes and it's relationship.
Search a subtree by giving the sequence of node, and status of node(for example "Occupied" / "Free").
Change node status, for example "Occupied" / "Free".
Modify tree structure.
Delete tree structure / subtree.

